# Distributing work shifts

Tags: algorithm

I am faced with the following problem:

I have (as in input) the following information:

1. Number of shifts available per type.
2. Expectations for available people per half an hour interval.

I am looking for an algorithm to help me accomplish this task. I can handle PHP code rather well however the idea behind the whole thing is a bit ... well non-existent.

I will further explain the problem.

I have a set of shifts that are available to me e.g.

12 shifts that are 4 hours long
10 shifts that are 6 hours long
14 shifts that are 8 hours long
3 shifts that are 12 hours long

and I have a requirement that at:
9:00 I need 3 people working
9:30 5 people working
10:00 16 people working

and so on.

Now I know that It might be impossible to compile the requirements at 100% and this is OK. The question is what approach to use in order to achieve at least sort of close to expectations result.

Thank you in advance. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything you're trying to optimize for? For instance, trying to ensure that people work for roughly the same amount of time?

Comment: @seaotternerd The usual goal is to minimize spill.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck this is the goal yes. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I've never really put my mind to it myself. Wikipedia told me that scheduling in the general form is kind of difficult (NP hard).

Comment: Well I was thinking that I can actually bruteforce the whole thing like try all possible options and output 3 that are the closest to the desired result however with 100+ employees per day that wouldn't be that efficient. I am pretty sure there is some kind of mathematical approach to the whole thing however I can't seem to find it somewhere explained.

Comment: Could you give actual data for one day? In eg. CSV format.

Comment: Are you supposed to use all the available shifts, or to minimize the work hours done? Is the expected number of people working at a given time a minimum you should meet if at all possible?

Comment: I should meet the closest to what is expected from the program.